# Using Properties of a Dense Set to prove characteristics of a continuous function

Tags: analysis, continuity, proof-verification

> **1.** If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in a dense set $E$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$
>   **2.** If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ in dense set $E$ , then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My Solution;
**Number 1**
Assume for a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ , $f(c) \neq0$ and let $\epsilon = |f(c)|$
As $f$ is continuous there exists a $\delta >0 \ \ s.t \ \ |x-c|<\delta \implies \ |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$
But as E is dense there will exist points $x \in \epsilon$ in the interval $(c- \delta, c+\delta)$ such that $f(x)=0$  for these points;
$$|0-f(c)|=||-f(c)|=|f(c)|<\epsilon = |f(c)|$$ which is absurd and gives our contradiction.
Is this correct??

**Number 2**
For this I will try to use a similar approach to above but my problem is that I can't seem to figure out a suitable $\epsilon$ to use.
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 is fine.

For number2 consider $g-f$.